# Regularity of Weak Solutions

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega  = \left( {0,1} \right) \times \left( {0,1} \right), f \in L^2 \left( \Omega \right)$ and $u$ is weak solution of boundary problem 
$$\left\{ \begin{gathered}
   - {\partial _x}\left( {\left( {2 + x} \right){u_x}} \right) - {\partial _y}\left( {\left( {2 + y} \right){u_y}} \right) = f \hfill \\
  {\left. u \right|_{\partial \Omega }} = 0. \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$$
Prove that $u \in {H^2}\left( \Omega  \right)$.

Weak solution of that boundary problem is a function $u$ such that
$$\int_\Omega  {\left( {2 + x} \right){u_x}{v_x} + \left( {2 + y} \right){u_y}{v_y}}  = \int_\Omega  {fv} ,\forall v \in H_0^1\left( \Omega  \right).$$
I dont know how to prve $u \in H^2$ i.e we must prove ${\left\| {{u_{xx}}} \right\|_{{L^2}\left( \Omega  \right)}},{\left\| {{u_{yy}}} \right\|_{{L^2}\left( \Omega  \right)}},{\left\| {{u_{xy}}} \right\|_{{L^2}\left( \Omega  \right)}} <  + \infty .$

Comment: Would you know how to do it if the $2+x$ and $2+y$ weren't there, i.e. do you know how to argue for elliptic regularity of the Dirichlet Poisson equation?

Comment: I dont know. I think we can use integral by part.

Comment: There is more to elliptic regularity than that. Look it up, it is a standard subject, and in it this is a standard problem (a linear elliptic problem in divergence form). (Note that the reason why this is elliptic regularity and not just Lax-Milgram is that you want to have $u \in H^2$ rather than merely $u \in H^1$: that is, more derivatives than appear in the weak formulation make sense.)

Comment: If $u$ is solution of 
$$\left\{ \begin{gathered}
   - {\partial _x}\left( {\left( {2 + x} \right){u_x}} \right) - {\partial _y}\left( {\left( {2 + y} \right){u_y}} \right) = f  \\
  {\left. u \right|_{\partial \Omega }} = 0  \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. \quad (1)$$
then $u \in {H^2}( \Omega  ) \cap H_0^1( \Omega  )$.
If $u$ is solution of 
$$\int_\Omega  {\left( {2 + x} \right){u_x}{v_x} + \left( {2 + y} \right){u_y}{v_y}}  = \int_\Omega  {fv} ,\forall v \in H_0^1\left( \Omega  \right). \quad (2)$$
My question is if $u$ is solution of (2). How to prove it solution of (1).

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But going from the weak formulation that only guarantees $u \in H^1_0$ up to the strong formulation that expects $u \in H^2$ is an elliptic regularity result, so you're going to need elliptic regularity machinery to prove it. It is not as simple as just integrating by parts (since you have no guarantee that this integration by parts even makes sense until you prove the desired result).

Comment: Still, as elliptic regularity problems go, this is about as easy as they come, as it is of the form $-\nabla \cdot(D(\mathbf{x})\nabla u)=f$ where $D(\mathbf{x})$ is a uniformly positive definite matrix.